# TypeScript error in Angular2 code: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: typescript, angular, commonjs

I have defined the following Angular2 component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error on line 5:

```
src/app/app.component.ts(5,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
```

I believe module.id is referring to the CommonJS `module` variable (see [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html)). I have specified the CommonJS module system in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "src"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

How can I correct the TypeScript error?

Comment: I don't think **module** is something that's provided to you at compile time.

Comment: Well it is compiling correctly for me in [this project](https://github.com/archfirst/angular2-seed-sass/blob/master/src/app/components/app.component.ts). I don't know how!!! So I tried to isolate this in a simpler project and it is not working there. So trying to figure out what is making it work in the first project.

Comment: You can declare a `module.d.ts` file with the content: `declare var module: any;`. Then reference this file from your bootstrap `/// <reference path="path/to/typings/module.d.ts" />`

Comment: In typings.json ambientDependencies: node

Comment: @yurzui, you nailed it on the head! Can you please write it out as an answer so that I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Update**

If you use **Typescript 2^** just use the following command:

```
npm i @types/node --save-dev
```

(instead of `--save-dev` you can just use shortcut `-D`)

or install it globally:

```
npm i @types/node --global
```

You can also specify `typeRoots` or `types` in your tsconfig.json if you want but **[by default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)**.

**Old version**

You need to install node ambientDependencies. Typings.json

```
"ambientDependencies": {
    "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#138ad74b9e8e6c08af7633964962835add4c91e2",
```

Another way can use [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) manager to install node definition file globally:

```
typings install dt~node --global --save-dev
```

Then your typings.json file will look like this:

```
"globalDependencies": {
  "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160608110640"
}
```

Comment: Two points: 
1. Remember to add the reference to the top of your root typescript file thus:
/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
2. Editing the typings.json file as shown by @yurzui worked for me but initially I just did this: 
> typings install node --ambient --save
Which updated the typings.json file [with a different version] and didn't work as the index.d.ts file threw scores of errors at transpile time.
FYI: I'm using Angular Beta.16

Comment: @yurzui How do you add a reference to it from your bootstrap?

Comment: The command `npm install @types/node --save` fixed this for me

Comment: `npm install @types/node --save` was enough for me.

Comment: Typings should be devDependencies since they are used by TypeScript for type checking and transpiling so they should be installed using `npm install -D @types/node` since they aren't used in the transpiled code.

Answer (score 49):

For those looking to do this with Typescript 2.x and @types, here's what you need to do:

1. `npm install -D @types/node`
2. Include `types: ["node"]` under `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

I had a tough time finding the instructions for step 2.

Reference: [Typescript issue 9184](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9184)

**Edit:**

You could also do:

2. Include `"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]` under `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file.  This is instead of the `types` property and has the benefit of automatically including any `@types` you install with npm.

**For example:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

**[Second edit]**
[Apparently](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9208#issuecomment-249183258), with the latest typescript, you only need `typeRoots` or `types` if `tsconfig.json` is not in the root of your project or your types are not stored in `node_modules/@types`.

Comment: @msanford yes, nested within. I'll make the answer more explicit.

Comment: Thanks so much for step 2! Was bashing my head with this for a couple of days.

Comment: After adding "types": ["node"] to my compiler options. all my spec.ts test files fail with cannot find name 'expect', 'it', 'describe', 'foreach' etc....

Comment: Adding types: ["node"] to tsconfig.json didn't work for me. I had to add it in src/tsconfig.app.json. I was upgrading from Angular 8 to 9 and TS 3..5 to 3.8, perhaps something changed since.

Answer (score 14):

I hit this error when porting my @angular/angular2 Quickstart project into a new angular cli auto-generated project.

It seems that `moduleId: module.id` isn't needed anymore.

This is the latest auto-generated component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Removing all occurances resolved my errors.

Comment: Thanks - this was the one that did it for me while upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 5 :-)

Answer (score 11):

Instead of "ambient" try "global" by Typings 1.0

```
typings install dt~node --global --save
```

Answer (score 6):

`module.id`

cannot find the name module.

Follow following steps to resolves this issue,

step 1: Install node module by using the below command

```
npm i @types/node --save
```

Step 2: modify the file `tsconfig.app.json` under `src/app`

```
"types": [
    "node"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Two key points:

1. Register typings by running `typings install dt~node --global --save`. So you'll get the following section in `typings.json`:

   ```
   "globalDependencies": {
       "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160608110640"
   }
   ```
2. Add reference to the new module. Two ways:

   - Directly add a reference to a dependency in your TS

     `/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />`
   - Add `typings/index.d.ts` in the `files` section of the `tsconfig.json`

     ```
     {
         "files": [
             "typings/index.d.ts"
         ]
     }
     ```

See more [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#module-resolutions).

Answer (score 1):

I use VS 2015, and had same issues, but I have resolved using:

1. add the typings.json file from the angular.io website (2.0.0 final at the moment) and the run:

   ```
   typings install // don't forget to install typings globally
   ```

then

```
npm install -D @types/node --save
```

in the package.json I have

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "6.0.40",
...
```

2. in the typings.json I have the following configuration

   ```
   {
   "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module":"commonjs",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
       "types": []
   },
   "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "app-dist"
   ]
   }
   ```

I had to add the types as an empty array

3. check for duplicates, and if moduleId: module.id is still highlighted

p.s. to me personally is a strange issue, because as soon as you exclude typings inside typings.json, you have immediately highlighted 'module', but if you let it in, you have lot's of duplicates. Don't know who to blame, me, typescript or visual studio :)

Comment: pretty sure the devDependency to `@types/node` is enough - typings is not required after that. What may happen is the IDE not finding the reference but that's a different problem. It gets resolved simply by adding `/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />` on top of the file

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did that worked for me on Eclipse(Webclipse)/Windows.

Step 1:

Terminal

```
$ npm install @types/node --global --save
```

Step 2:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

In addition, I had the following dependencies in my package.json, so I was using typescript 2.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had a `tsconfig.app.json` that extended `tsconfig.json`. So when I added `"types": ["node"]` in `tsconfig.json`, it was being overridden by the "types" property in `tsconfig.app.json`. Adding "node" to the existing "types" property in `tsconfig.app.config` fixed it.

Comment: This was my issue kinda - the default angular  `tsconfig.app.json` defines a blank `types: []` which was overwriting not just the parent `types` but also causes the `typeRoots` to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

I installed in the project, and worked well

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Comment: Should be --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

It still did not work until i pasted this where i had module.id, on top of component. like this

> declare var module:  NodeModule; 
>   
> interface NodeModule 
> { 
>    id: string;
>   
>  }
>
> @Component({module.id})