# Please explain this SystemJs config

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying to learn angular2 however I am stuck with the SystemJS configuration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reloyalty Administration Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <!-- For Angular2 Routing -->
    <base href="/">


    <!-- Common Scripts-->
    <script src="/common/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/calendar-conf-events.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/chartjs-conf.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/form-component.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/gritter-conf.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/sparkline-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/tasks.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/zabuto_calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/bootstrap-inputmask/bootstrap-inputmask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>
    <script src="/dashboard/js/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->

    <script>


        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js',
                    main: 'main.js'
                },
                '@angular/core': {
                    main: 'bundles/core.umd.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                '@angular/compiler': {
                    main: 'bundles/compiler.umd.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                '@angular/common': {
                    main: 'bundles/common.umd.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {
                    main: 'bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                '@angular/platform-browser': {
                    main: 'bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                rxjs: {
                    main: 'bundles/Rx.umd.min.js',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            },
            map: {
                'app': '.', // where my app is. '.' means relative
                '@angular': '/js/node_modules/@angular',
                'rxjs': '/js/node_modules/rxjs'
            }
        });
        System.import('management/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <!-- end AngularJS 2-->
</head>

<body>

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>

</body>
</html>
```

My file structure is :

```
management/
├── app/
│   ├── app.component.ts
|   ├── root.module.ts
├──main.ts
```

main.ts :

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {RootModule} from "./app/root.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(RootModule);
```

root.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';


@NgModule({
    imports:      [BrowserModule], // what my Angular Application needs
    declarations: [AppComponent], // the view classes that belong to this module.
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent], // which class to boostrap
})
export class RootModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>BLAAH is best !!! OMGOMGOMG blagh assdsdasd</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

I have read all the documentation systemjs provides but can't seem to comprehend what is going on in the configuration.

For example if I write:

```
System.import('main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

I get those errors in the console ?

```
GET http://merchant.localhost:1337/main.js 404 (Not Found)
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://merchant.localhost:1337/main.js(…)
```

=========================================================================

------------------------------------EDIT 1-------------------------------

=========================================================================

I changed:

```
System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                main: 'main.js'
            },
            '@angular/core': {
                main: 'bundles/core.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            '@angular/compiler': {
                main: 'bundles/compiler.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            '@angular/common': {
                main: 'bundles/common.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {
                main: 'bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            '@angular/platform-browser': {
                main: 'bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                main: 'bundles/Rx.umd.min.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        },
        map: {
            'app': 'management', // where my app is. '.' means relative
            '@angular': '/js/node_modules/@angular',
            'rxjs': '/js/node_modules/rxjs'
        }
    });
    System.import('app')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

So now my app is located in the management folder and I start it with "app" which knows that it has to run **main.js** and so on. This works. Great. So I proceeded and created a **root.component.html** which does not get loaded now. 
Here is the code :

root.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'root-component',
    templateUrl: 'root.component.html'
})
export class RootComponent { }
```

And the error:

```
GET http://merchant.localhost:1337/root.component.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you really need to map the `app` to `management` folder instead of `.`. You have renamed your root and that's why you are having these troubles it seems.

You will also need to fix `main: './main.js'` in packages and use `app` as a module name.

So what happens is that you tell System.Js that there is a package which name is `app` and that you can find it under `./management/main.js`.

P.S. I am not a super big expert on System.Js, so I might be wrong, but I managed to run it with Angular2 tutorial :)

Comment: renaming app:'.' to app:'management' and then System.import('main') gives me "GET http://merchant.localhost:1337/main 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: You should import `app` instead of `main`. System.js has no idea what 'main' is.

Comment: I think you also need to fix the package to be `main: './main.js'`

Comment: I will post an EDIT with changes and current error :)

Comment: You need to use module.id in there:  moduleId: module.id. Not sure about all the details, but long story short it allows relative references to the file instead of from the root. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular2-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component

Comment: assets/management/app/root/root.component.ts(3,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.

Comment: You need to tell typescript where to look for it. npm install @types/node --global --save. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700693/typescript-error-in-angular2-code-cannot-find-name-module

Comment: Same :(((((((((

Comment: I had to isntall it via npm install @types/node

Comment: just verify that your package json have this in dev dependencies "@types/node": "6.0.42", this should be enough to find module. Sometimes VS has some cache or something, so you might need to restart it. At least I experienced it did not figure out this on the fly as it should.

Comment: after installing this and restarting the server I get "zone.js:232 Error: (SystemJS) module is not defined(…)" ??? I have it included in my index.html and it has been loaded into the browser .

Comment: You should probably expand the error in console and check what's wrong. Most likely you have to add something to your system.js since it's not under the same `management` folder or something...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465367/systemjs-module-is-not-defined

Comment: I have only these scripts:`<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>`