# Relative Path: Cannot set moduleId because 'module' is nowhere to be found, why is this so?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    moduleId: module.id, //Error goes here: [ts] Cannot find name 'module'.
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/products/product-list.component.css']
})
```

I used Visual Studio code on Ubuntu. I taught it was Visual Studio code only but when I compile, it gave me the same error.

Is this a bug? If not, is there a way to reference the 'module'?

BTW Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using dist folder or something anywhere or straight quickstart setup only?

Comment: Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36701222/5706293