# Webclipse errors loading typescript files

Tags: json, node.js, typescript2.0

I have installed typescript using *sudo npm install -g typescript*, which seems to work because *tsc -version* returns *Version 2.2.2*. I also tried installing it locally as this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700693/typescript-error-in-angular2-code-cannot-find-name-module/42103461#42103461) suggested. I believe that I have everything else installed correctly because the IDE opens other files correctly.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.0.

Error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node.js could not be found.  If it is installed to a location not on the PATH, please specify the location in the TypeScript preferences.
```

The tsconfig.json is below. I believe that the value of *typeRoots* should point to the *@types* location. And indeed the same directory where the .json file resides, there is a *node_modules/@types* directory, which I would have thought should enable typescript.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript preferences mentioned in the error message are in the Webclipse preferences.
Simply enter the path returned by `which node` in a shell.

[image: Screen shot of configuration]