# Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular 2 project. I am trying to add data-table component in my project. But facing above error at the time of compilation.what needs to be done to get the required output. please guide me in a right direction.

```js
admin-products.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { DataTableResource } from 'angular-4-data-table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  products: Product[];
  filteredProducts: any[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  tableResource:DataTableResource<Product>;
  items: Product[] = [];
  itemCount: Number;
 
  constructor(private productService:ProductService) { 
  this.subscription = this.productService.getAll().
  subscribe(products =>{
    this.filteredProducts= this.products = products;
    this.initializeTable(products);
    
  });
  }
    private initializeTable(products:Product[]){
      this.tableResource.query({ offset:0})
      .then(items => this.items = items);
        this.tableResource.count()
        .then(count => this.itemCount = count);

    }  
  
     reloadItems(params){
      if(!this.tableResource) return;
      
      this.tableResource.query(params)
      .then(items => this.items = items);
     }
  
    filter(query: string){
       this.filteredProducts = (query) ?
           this.products.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
           this.products;
    }
     ngOnDestroy(){
          this.subscription.unsubscribe()
     } 
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```css
admin-products.component.html


<p>
    <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">New Product</a>
</p>
<p>
   
<input 
 #query
 (keyup)="filter(query.value)"
 type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">  
</p>
<data-table
    [items]="items"
    [itemCount]="itemCount"
    (reload)="reloadItems($event)"
    >
 <data-table-column
   [property]="'title'"
   [header]="'title'"
   [sortable]="true"
   [resizable]="true"
 >
 
 <data-table-column
 [property]="'price'"
 [header]="'Price'"
 [sortable]="true"
 [resizable]="true"
>

 <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
    {{item.price | currency:'USD':true}}
 </ng-template> 
</data-table-column>

<data-table-column
 [property]="'$key'"
>
 
<ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
     <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products', item.$key]">Edit</a>
 </ng-template> 
 </data-table-column>

</data-table>
```

```html
app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import{NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BsNavbarComponent } from './bs-navbar/bs-navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';
import { OrderSuccessComponent } from './order-success/order-success.component';
import { MyOrdersComponent } from './my-orders/my-orders.component';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from './admin/admin-products/admin-products.component';
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from './admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {CustomFormsModule} from 'ng2-validation';
import {DataTableModule} from 'angular-4-data-table';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard as AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AdminAuthGuard as AdminAuthGuard } from './admin-auth-guard.service';
import { ProductFormComponent } from './admin/product-form/product-form.component';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BsNavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    CheckOutComponent,
    OrderSuccessComponent,
    MyOrdersComponent,
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    ProductFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CustomFormsModule,
    DataTableModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent}, 
    {path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent},
    {path: 'shopping-cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'check-out', component: CheckOutComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'order-success', component: OrderSuccessComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'my/orders',component: MyOrdersComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'admin/products/new', component:ProductFormComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard,AdminAuthGuard]}, 
    {path: 'admin/products/:id', component:ProductFormComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard,AdminAuthGuard]},
    {path: 'admin/products', component: AdminProductsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard,AdminAuthGuard]},
    {path: 'admin/orders', component: AdminOrdersComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard,AdminAuthGuard]}  
  ])    
],
  providers: [
    
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminAuthGuard,
    UserService,
    CategoryService,
    ProductService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

should be done to get the required output . please guide me in a right direction

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to compiler configuration problems. You're trying to add external components and for that you need to make some modifications to your angular project like in your tsconfig.json file. These usually are provided by the library documentation. See this related question for instance: [TypeScript error in Angular2 code: Cannot find name 'module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700693/typescript-error-in-angular2-code-cannot-find-name-module)

However, since you're trying to use a table **I would highly recommend** you some well known Component Libraries for Angular, all of them have well documented and explained examples:

1. Angular Material(My favorite) - https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples
2. Prime NG - https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

If you decide to do that, just follow the Getting Started of any of them and you should be able to use a well built Table Component and more easily find the solution to related bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Gustavo Morais sir. But to get rid of that compiler configuration and all those things I have tried with angular 5 command of data table "npm i angular5-data-table --save "and imported  from the same in app.module.ts. now it is compiling but showing this runtime error: unexpected closing tag "data-table" I ave checked admin-product.component.html file but I am not getting whre I made the mistake. Can you please help me out on this?

Comment: In the .html you've posted you have this tags: <data-table-coloumn
   [property]="'title'"
   [header]="'title'"
   [sortable]="true"
   [resizable]="true"
 > 

it this the word column is written wrong, perhaps try to fix it and see if it fixes the problem.

Like this:

<data-table-column
   [property]="'title'"
   [header]="'title'"
   [sortable]="true"
   [resizable]="true"
 >

Comment: Yes sir I corrected that mistake. Now the data table is showing the information but it is showing only currency info of products in the table. how can I get all info that is products along with its price with edit option in each row. where I need to modify the code?? Can you please tell me?? @Gustavo Morais

Comment: it is showing only one column that is title and in the title column it is showing prices of the products. I want in title column the name of the product and in the price column the price of the product.@Gustavo Morais

Comment: Check your Product model if it's written exactly as you use here [property]="'price'" and [property]="'title'", make sure the items variable has this items written like this. Also, update your code in the question or open a new question because It will be easier for you to share your new errors.

Comment: Yes sir, Thank you for your support.

Comment: I am using angular 4 version for data table again and there is some issue with typescript so I have installed typings.json file with global dependencies. but still it is showing cannot find 'module' error in pagination.component,ts, row.component.ts and in table component.ts. what changes should I do in typings.json file in order to get rid of this error.